# Intellji Cucumber Lambda symbol given not recoginised

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, cucumber-junit

Newbie/refresher at Cucumber in Java and have searched stack overflow trying various fixes (removing the scope from the JUnit dependency, changing the program structure language to 10, restarting and rebuilding and so forth) and I am at my wits end.

I cannot get the Given symbol to be found in Intellji.  It is using a Lambda expression but it is not found as below:

[image]
import cucumber.api.java.en.given also shows as greyed out
[image]

pom.xml is as follows (as you can see I have tried a lot with JUNIT dependencies.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>CucumberBasicsKM01</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.10.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
                <version>7.14.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-xml-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <!-- Work around. Surefire does not include enough
                             information to disambiguate between different
                             examples and scenarios. -->
                        <configurationParameters>
                            cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

I would appreciate if anyone could tell me how to set my pom.xml file correctly to recognize the Given symbol and so forth in Lambda expressions.

Thank you for all your help.

Kirsty

Comment: You don't have an import statement, so Java / your IDE doesn't know where to find the `Given` class. If you click the red lightbulb does it offer you a suggested import to use?

Comment: No HeroCC it doesn't give me the option to add the import statement for the import cucumber.api.java.en.given- which I do know the Lambda expression is from. - see above with image added

Comment: Looks like the import you have is wrong, too.  Make sure you know what the fully resolved class name is in the Cucumber JAR you depend on.  Open the JAR and find the precise package hierarchy and class name.

Comment: duffymo where is the  Cucumber JAR located?

Comment: IntelliJ shows it under External Libraries in the Project pane.

Comment: duffymo ok the jar is 7.14 as in the following: cucumber-j-unit-7.14.0.jar   What part of the pom.xml above needs to be corrected with this?

Comment: I don't know about correcting.  I'd open the JAR and find the Given class that you need.  Check the package hierarchy.  Make sure it appears.

Comment: No luck - could someone give me the correct link from the maven repo for JUNIT for Lambda expressions in JAVA so I can add it to my dependencies and try?  https://mvnrepository.com/ ??

Answer (score 0):

Bro just to notify you, in the previous versions of cucumber you needed to do the following:

-implements En with your stepdefinition class

and the package to implements that 'En' class belongs to:
import io.cucumber.java8.En;

But if you see the current version of cucumber, this java8 package does not exist anymore, if you try to import the package you could see that En class is in another package, try with it.

With older version of cucumber:

```
package com.example;
import io.cucumber.java8.En;

public class StepDefinitions implements En {
    public StepDefinitions() {
        Given("I have {int} cukes in my belly", (Integer cukes) -> {
            System.out.format("Cukes: %n\n", cukes);
        });
    }
}
```

Try it and let me know what were your results .